# Change paused animation's play state to running on click of a link

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-animations

Using CSS and Javascript (preferably not jQuery as I don't understand as well) how do I set a CSS animation to go **from a pause state to a play state** triggered when the user clicks a text link (href) as opposed to a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple. Just set the `animation-play-state` to `paused` initially and then add a class which sets the `animation-play-state` to `running` when the anchor link is clicked.

Add a `return false` to the event handler to prevent the default action of the anchor from happening.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("play-link");
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('play');
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  animation: shake 1s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes shake {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
div.play {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animate'>Some text</div>
<a href='#' class='play-link'>Play</a>
<div class='animate'>Some text</div>
<a href='#' class='play-link'>Play</a>
```

---

You can even toggle between `paused` and `running` states by toggling the `play` class on and off.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("play-link");
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('play');
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  animation: shake 4s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }  
}
div.play {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animate'>Some text</div>
<a href='#' class='play-link'>Toggle Play State</a>
<div class='animate'>Some text</div>
<a href='#' class='play-link'>Toggle Play State</a>
```

Comment: Thank you works perfect - how would I amend it so that the a tag that appears as 'Play' runs animation for div one and a similar script with a seperate a tag does the same for div two (in other words two independent links that fire play for respective animations). Would I be required to add this as a standalone function?

Comment: @Darren: I have updated the answer with the method. You would basically have to traverse through all link elements (I am doing it based on class), assign the event handler to them. Within the event handler we have to find the `div` corresponding to the link that was clicked and then toggle/add the class which triggers the animation.